# lodash: deep copy only few properties from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array with the below properties

```
data = [ { 'id' : 1,
'name': 'xyz',
'age': 21,
'gender': 'M',
'address': '123 xyz'},
{ 'id' : 2,
'name': 'abc',
'age': 23,
'gender': 'F',
'address': '456 abc'}
]
```

I am trying to build an new array with just few of the properties and update a property (address) like this

data1=  [ { 'id' : 1,
'name': 'xyz',
'address1': '123 xyz'},
{ 'id' : 2,
'name': 'abc',
'address1': '456 abc'}
]

I tried using map and remove functions.
But wanted to see if there is an easy way to do it. I tried using combinations of some of the lodash functions but not successful.

Comment: I don't think you even need lodash for this tbh...

Comment: @SumnerEvans - Or basically anything else, these days. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data1 = data.map(d => {
return {'id' : d.id, 'name': d.name, 'address1': d.address}
})
```

Just a simple map is enough, no need of any lib.

Comment: What if I want to add id and name as child of info.something like info.id = d.id, info.name = d.name and address1 = d.address

Comment: `let data1 = data.map(d => ( {info:{'id' : d.id, 'name': d.name}, 'address1': d.address}))`
@indra257

Answer (score 2):

How about just using the [`Array.prototype.map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

```js
var data = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'xyz',
    'age': 21,
    'gender': 'M',
    'address': '123 xyz'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'abc',
    'age': 23,
    'gender': 'F',
    'address': '456 abc'
  }
];

var data1 = data.map(x => ({id: x.id, name: x.name, address1: x.address}));

// modify data
data[0].id = 3;

// only data has been modified, not data1
console.log(data);
console.log(data1);
```

Comment: Yes, I updated my map accordingly. @OP, FYI the terminology you want is "rename the key", not an update. Updating normally refers to changing the value (changing the address text, for example).

Comment: @Summer Thanks a lot. But I just figured out, I need to add id and name as child of info. something like info.id = d.id, info.name = d.name and address1 = d.address

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `map` with destructuring, and shorthand property notation to create the new objects:

```
// Extracts `id`, `name`, and `address`...
//     \−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
const result = data.map(({id, name, address: address1}) => ({id, name, address1}));
// Renames `address` to `address1` −−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Builds new object with result −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−/
```

Live example:

```js
const data = [ { 'id' : 1,
'name': 'xyz',
'age': 21,
'gender': 'M',
'address': '123 xyz'},
{ 'id' : 2,
'name': 'abc',
'age': 23,
'gender': 'F',
'address': '456 abc'}
];

const result = data.map(({id, name, address: address1}) => ({id, name, address1}));

console.log(result);
```

Or you can do the renaming when creating the new object:

```
const result = data.map(({id, name, address}) => ({id, name, address1: address}));
```